# Google Cloud Platform console error?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When I go to the following page in the Google Cloud Platform console..

https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances

..and click on an instance's name, I get the following error:

**"Cannot read property 'fetchPolicy' of undefined"**

[image: Console Error]

What is going on here and is there anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 1):

This has likely been fixed since the posting but if anyone comes across this error in the future the best way to go about troubleshooting is to file an [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) with Google with the details of the error so that they can be aware of it as soon as possible.